# Slowcheetah Transforms for Azure Webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, slowcheetah

In my experience, Slowcheetah does not work with Azure Webjobs.

I'm just looking for confirmation as to whether this is the case (or not).

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I've used this tutorial and it work fine : [SlowCheetah VS 2015](http://www.christophdemaskey.com/slowcheetah-in-vs-2015-rc/).
Keep in mind that a webjob is just a console app (and more...)

1. Add the [slowcheetah nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/) to your webjob project.
2. Add the app.config transform to your project, for example app.Debug.config and app.Release.config
3. Edit your *.csproj file and add these lines (depending on the name and number of transformation you want :

   ```
   <None Include="App.Release.config">
       <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
       <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
   </None>
   <None Include="App.Debug.config">
       <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
       <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
   </None>
   ```

above these lines :

```
    <None Include="App.config">
        <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
```

4. Reload your project and it should work.

Comment: Did not work for me, sadly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225504/why-are-config-transforms-not-applied-when-i-manually-publish-a-consol-app-as-an/43249588#43249588

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Web API project that deploys an Azure WebJob (SDK 2.5), which uses SlowCheetah transforms. When my Web App is published to Azure, the WebJob App.config contains the transformed values from the SlowCheetah transform. I'm confident it works as you'd expect.

Comment: Surprised by your response, I tried again. My XSLT is fine, as it works in the preview. It works on the Web.config of my Site. But it does not work with the App.config of my WebJob projects. Are you sure it works?

Comment: Yes, my transforms can be confirmed in the Azure WebJob by pulling and viewing the App.config via FTP. What do you see if you publish the WebJob project to a local folder?

Comment: I have not been able to Publish to a local folder. I use the Publish Profiles and Publish as an Azure Webjob context menu item to deploy. But yes, I used FTP to verify that the generated config was not properly transformed by SlowCheetah.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the mystery, I believe, regarding the reason this is failing for some and not for others.

To ensure this works, in your Package Manger Console, before installing the SlowCheetah nuget package, run the command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted".

I bet everyone who has this failing, if they check their output log during install of the package, will see the ps1 script failing to execute which is setting up the necessary build settings for the transformation to take place.

Be sure to set your execution policy back to a desired security configuration after this is complete since the unrestricted policy is a potential threat.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that SlowCheetah does not work for me when publishing console applications to Azure as Web Jobs [from Visual Studio 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs#convertnolink).

My issue is described in this stackoverflow question: [Why are config transforms not applied when I manually publish a console app as an Azure webjob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225504/why-are-config-transforms-not-applied-when-i-manually-publish-a-consol-app-as-an/43249588#43249588) and there's also an answer there that provides a quick fix for the problem.

Additionally I've opened [a GitHub Issue](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/240) in the SlowCheetah repo.

Answer (score -1):

For me it was also not working with the Publishing Profiles and the Azure WebJob. The workaround was that i've created a new Build Configuration with the full name of the publishing profile and then it started working and transformed the app.config.