# Why are config transforms not applied when I manually publish a console app as an Azure webjob?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-webjobs, config-transformation

I have a console application that I am deploying to Azure as a Web Job. I do this manually from Visual Studio 2015 by right-clicking the project and choosing "[Publish as Azure WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs#convertnolink)".

I am now at a point where I need to deploy this app to several different environments (ex: dev, test, prod etc). In each environment the console app needs to run with different config settings.

To get this done, I've installed [Slow Cheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) v2.5.48 and setup multiple config transform files - one for each environment.

I've also created dedicated publish profiles in my project - one for each environment - and I've made sure the profile names match the names of the config transform files.

When I manually publish via the Publish wizard in VS (as described above), I find that the config transforms are not applied. Instead, the "base" .config file are present on the target app service.

Why are the transforms not applied when publishing this way and how can I fix that?

Comment: Have you had a look at this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34279432/4167200

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that did not work for me (referring to adding `<TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>` as per the top voted answer in that question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly check you have already [build configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) called "dev" ,” test” like below.

[image]

Then I suggest you could check you have a right app config file in your project like below.

[image]

At last, you could make sure you have select the right build configuration.

[image]

Besides, I suggest you could open your .csproj file and ensure that the App.dev.config tag’s IsTransformFile is true.

```
<None Include="App.dev.config">
      <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
    </None>
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding a build configuration with the same name as my publish profile did the trick. One thing to pay attention to is that I had to choose this configuration in the "Settings" tab of the publish wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try with:

```
< xdt:Transform="Replace">
```

Comment: Hi @gaurav-agarwal. Congratulations on your very first StackOverflow answer! I already have this type of transform in my file. The issue seems to be that the file is not being read at all, regardless of what's in it.